# pgx tls connection throws client cert invalid error for valid cert

Tags: postgresql, go, pgx

I'm trying to use pgx to make a TLS connection to a postgres 10 db.

My connection string is similar to: `"host='my-host.com' port='5432' dbname='my-db' user='my-db-user' sslmode='verify-full' sslcert='/path/to/db_user.crt' sslkey='/path/to/db_user.key' sslrootcert='/path/to/ca_roots.pem'"`

When I run this directly with `psql` on the command-line, it works, so the cert and key files must be valid. `db_user.crt` and `db_user.key` are both PEM files. (the command-line also works with `sslmode='verify-full'`, so the rootcert should also be ok)

But when I initialize a `pgx` pool with that connection string, it fails with:

> FATAL: connection requires a valid client certificate (SQLSTATE 28000)

Is go expecting something other than PEM? Or is there a different way ssl cert and key pair is supposed to be initialized with pgx?

##### Code

```
import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/jackc/pgx/v4"
    "github.com/jackc/pgx/v4/pgxpool"
)

type mockLogger struct{}

func (ml *mockLogger) Log(ctx context.Context, level pgx.LogLevel, msg string, data map[string]interface{}) {
    fmt.Printf("[%s] %s : %+v\n", level.String(), msg, data)
}

func connect() error {
    connStr := "host='my-host.com' port='5432' dbname='my-db' user='my-db-user' sslmode='verify-full' sslcert='/path/to/db_user.crt' sslkey='/path/to/db_user.key' sslrootcert='/path/to/ca_roots.pem'"
    poolCfg, err := pgxpool.ParseConfig(connStr)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    poolCfg.ConnConfig.Logger = &mockLogger{}
    poolCfg.ConnConfig.LogLevel = pgx.LogLevelTrace
    fmt.Printf("using connection string: \"%s\"\n", poolCfg.ConnString())

    connPool, err := pgxpool.ConnectConfig(context.TODO(), poolCfg)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    connPool.Close()
    return nil
}

func main() {
    if err := connect(); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

Output from calling `connect()`:

```
using connection string: "host='my-host.com' port='5432' dbname='my-db' user='my-db-user' sslmode='require' sslcert='/path/to/db_user.crt' sslkey='/path/to/db_user.key' sslrootcert='/path/to/ca_roots.pem'"
[info] Dialing PostgreSQL server : map[host:my-host.com]
[error] connect failed : map[err:failed to connect to `host=my-host.com user=my-db-user database=my-db`: server error (FATAL: connection requires a valid client certificate (SQLSTATE 28000))]
failed to connect to `host=my-host.com user=my-db-user database=my-db`: server error (FATAL: connection requires a valid client certificate (SQLSTATE 28000))
```

Comment: Please remove the extraneous items (like presumably mockLogger) and add the necessary ones (like suitable `import`)

Comment: @jjanes ok, added the imports. `mockLogger` isn't extraneous, however, b/c that's how the log lines from pgx are showing up at the bottom (the lines beginning with `[info]` and `[error]`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Summary

Turns out for go, the cert pointed to by `sslcert` needed to contain the full ***client cert chain***.

When `/path/to/db_user.crt` contained the client cert followed by client cert chain, the `pgx` connection worked.

Whereas the `psql` command worked in both cases:

- when `sslcert` was just the leaf client cert without the chain
- when `sslcert` contained client cert + chain

Not sure why psql was fine without the full chain, but it works now.

##### Details

Under-the-hood, pgx uses the [`pgconn`](https://github.com/jackc/pgconn) module to create the connection. That, in turn, is just calling [`tls.X509KeyPair`](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/tls#X509KeyPair) on the contents of the `sslcert` and `sslkey` files.

[pgconn/config.go](https://github.com/jackc/pgconn/blob/15f8e6323e113feb44678e5cb16cfbeba4630bf6/config.go#L617):

```
func configTLS(settings map[string]string, thisHost string, parseConfigOptions ParseConfigOptions) ([]*tls.Config, error) {
    [...]
    sslcert := settings["sslcert"]
    sslkey := settings["sslkey"]
    [...]
    if sslcert != "" && sslkey != "" {
        [...]
        certfile, err := ioutil.ReadFile(sslcert)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("unable to read cert: %w", err)
        }
        cert, err := tls.X509KeyPair(certfile, pemKey)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("unable to load cert: %w", err)
        }
        tlsConfig.Certificates = []tls.Certificate{cert}
```